# How compatible is OpenAL?

Tags: java, lwjgl, sound, openal

I'm making a game that needs sounds and LWJGL uses OpenAL.

I was wondering out of 1.0, 1.1, C 1.0 and C 1.1 which would be the best to pick? I don't know what the C is but it's there in LWJGL :).

My point is what is the difference between these versions? And also how compatible are both are these as far as system requirements go?

Comment: You might consider using OpenAL Soft the open source and more up to date version of the OpenAL implementation.  It's pretty much a drop in replacement.

Comment: Which technology to use questions are off topic. Typically going with the newest version of anything is your best bet. It's *supposed* to be more compatible.

Comment: @byte I think it could be ok since they are asking the differences.

Comment: @GameDev-er I disagree. The differences they'd want to know would be related to compatibility for the project they're working on. Surely they don't want to know *all* the changes and it wouldn't be reasonable to answer them here anyway. Additionally, the answer you provided doesn't even answer the question as you appeared to interpret it.

Comment: Please note, that OpenAL is not considered as an open industrial stndard, like OpenGL or OpenVG. It is not maintained by Khronos group. You can not be sure that it will be developed or supported by anybody in the future.

Comment: @IvanKuckir: And how is that different from COLLADA or any other Khronos standard? You can't be sure those will be developed or supported in the future either.

Comment: Compatible with what?

Comment: Doom 3 used OpenAL - you can be fairly certain that it is *well* supported on all PC hardware, although maybe not the latest versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even 1.1 is from 2008. So they are all pretty outdated. You should use the latest though. The [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenAL) says there's a version 2.0.7.0 from 3 years ago that's even newer that what you mentioned. You can also read about the supported platforms there and maybe figure a way to make the 2.0 version work with LWJGL.